# Open a windows application inside a browser

Tags: windows, process

Is it possible to open a windows application inside a browser ?
I have a windows application and I need to open it inside of a browser

Comment: No, this is not possible. But what _exactly_ are you trying to do? Where does this Windows application reside, and where do you want to open it, and what does "inside a browser" mean?

Comment: I meant by inside a browser, opening a windows application inside of a web one

Comment: That doesn't clarify. What Windows application? How would you imagine that to look? Where would it be executed from? But again, no, this is not possible.

Comment: maybe rewrite as ActiveX and force users to switch to IE?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible except in case you have a Visual Studio application and you rewrite it by using a webform based template.